# Can't read from NamedTemporaryFile after being written

Tags: python

I'm trying to download a file to a temp file and posting this file to another service. I tried this using NamedTemporaryFile but i'm being forced to close the file and reopen it.

```
def main():
    validate()
    logging.basicConfig(filename=sys.argv[2]+".log", level=logging.INFO)

    if(sys.argv[3][0:4] == "http"):
        filename = None
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile("w+b", delete=False) as file:
            download(file, sys.argv[3])
            #this logging prints nothing
            logging.debug(file.readlines())
    else:
        #this else just process a local file...


def download(file, url):
    logging.info("Downloading file " + sys.argv[3] + "...")
    start = time.time() * 1000
    r = requests.get(sys.argv[3], stream=True, timeout=2.0)

    #just a dummy check....
    if r.status_code == 200:
        for chunk in r.iter_content():
            file.write(chunk)

        file.flush()
    else:
        logging.error("Server returned an error")
        raise StandardError
```

If I reopen the file outside the with block and I tried to read it, it just works. I don't understand why I have to close the temporary file and reopen it.

Can someone give me an explanation about this. I'm pretty new in python dev.

Comment: the file writing doesn't actually take place until you close the file. Therefore you can't read from it until after you have closed it. the `with` statement closes it for you

Comment: I can read a file which is being written using flush() to force buffered bytes to be written to disk.

Comment: @TimCastelijns: This is not true.  After `flush()`ing, reads are guaranteed to be consistent with the written state.

Comment: @SamuelGarcía: `flush()` doesn't force any data being written to disk.  It only makes sure the process-local buffers are transferred to the OS.  The OS is free to keep the data in memory and write it later, as long as it guarantees that reads from the same file are consistent with what has been written.  If you want to force the data being written to disk, you need to call `os.fsync()`.

Comment: Well, yes, I just want to keep it simple. Since it is local access, I only want to be pushed to the IO layer. In this scenario I don't care if the file are stored as MMap segment or if it's really written to disk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that readlines() seems to read from the current file position on.
If you first seek to the start of the temporary file, you will get the lines.

```
file.seek(0)
logging.debug(file.readlines())
```